# geth shows last block 0, but on import says all blocks present

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm trying to restore a corrupt geth DB to a previous version, when I run geth it says

```
I1109 17:36:34.009514 core/blockchain.go:213] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I1109 17:36:34.009547 core/blockchain.go:214] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I1109 17:36:34.009555 core/blockchain.go:215] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
```

So I try to import from the backup I have but I see:

```
I1109 17:36:34.205342 cmd/utils/cmd.go:171] skipping batch 0, all blocks present [88e96d45 / dcdb0ade]
I1109 17:36:49.454992 cmd/utils/cmd.go:171] skipping batch 1, all blocks present [d43fb926 / 5f91e535]
I1109 17:37:14.511707 cmd/utils/cmd.go:171] skipping batch 2, all blocks present [fee1f84b / 1d3fe05c]
I1109 17:37:35.379504 cmd/utils/cmd.go:171] skipping batch 3, all blocks present [132d70a6 / dc2d938e]
```

I assume the issue is a corrupt db, as if I just leave it to run it says `Block synchronisation started` but then does nothing.

Do I need to re-sync from scratch?

Comment: It'll probably be faster to just fast-sync from scratch than to mess around with importing

Comment: @TjadenHess thats what I'll do then. Its frustrating though, I had only just finished downloading it about 1 hr before :/ Not sure what went wrong